# How to include Bourbon via node-sass within ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm, sass, node-sass, bourbon

Started a React project using ***create-react-app***. Both *node-sass* and *bourbon* have been added as dev-dependencies.

To what file should the following be added to inform node-sass of bourbon?
`require("bourbon").includePaths`

Comment: You can simply include gem source in your project manually or via yarn / npm / bower add it not in node_modules but in your public libraries in some folder eg. vendor and import from there scss mixins.

Comment: @Zydnar That's the process I'm wondering if could be avoided.

Comment: Probably there is some bourbon loader for webpack looking at global gems but basicly it will do the same in build process.

Comment: Do you plan to eject from CRA at some point?

Comment: @etarhan No plans to eject.

Comment: Not the prettiest, but for now I've decided to @import bourbon directly from the "node-modules" folder.